# Rails: uninitialized constant Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, uninitialized-constant

Here is my setup:

Routes:

```
resources :apps, except: [:index, :new], path: 'a' do
    resources :platforms, only: [:update]
end
```

Controller:

```
class Apps::PlatformsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_platform

    # PATCH/PUT /apps/1/platforms/1
    # PATCH/PUT /apps/1/platforms/1.json
    def update
        # do stuff ...
    end

    private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_platform
        @platform = App::Platform.find params[:id]
    end

end
```

View:

```
= link_to 'Update', app_platform_url(platform.app.slug, platform.id), method: :put
```

---

When clicking the link, I get the following error:

> uninitialized constant PlatformsController

---

Why does Rails look for `PlatformsController` and not `Apps::PlatformsController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know just `namespace`s and `scope`s require a nested module.

Comment: Do you know a better solution than namespacing every nested route? Cause that's creating ugly url helpers like `app_apps_platform_url`.

Comment: You could a block to namespace all the routes

Comment: Or rename you routes with the as option if the route names are the issue